# Object in texture and material view appear black

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

When i change from solid to texture and material view my object appears black, im in blender render engine with GLSL shading and Hemi added,

Here is my solid view, 
[image]

when i change from solid to texture my object appears black,
[image]

the same happens to solid to material
[image]

and the same for texture painting mode.
[image]

Any ideas what might cause the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a black image in the UV/Image editor that the object is linked to. For the material view, it is because you have that texture applied in the textures tab of the properties window.

## "Solutions" (There isn't actually anything wrong)

1. In texture paint mode, you can paint onto that texture and change its color.

[image]

2. You can disable that texture to keep it from showing up in the material preview.

[image]

3. You can put a different texture on it. For changing texture mode's display, go to the UV/Image editor and with the object in edit mode (so you can see the UVs), select a different image.